# Differences between ZMTP and AMQP protocols

Tags: rabbitmq, zeromq, amqp

I want to choose a message broker between the ZeroMQ and RabbitMQ for micro-services communications.

Question is which one is faster for data transfer? ZeroMQ(ZMTP protocol) Or RabbitMQ(AMQP protocol)?

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *" ... which one is **faster** for data transfer? "*

My bet is ZeroMQ being fastest, using **`inproc://`** Transport Class for **`PAIR/PAIR`** Scalable Formal Communication Pattern archetype. The same if moving data over cluster-wide using **`tipc://`** Transport Class and having also a few **`vmci://`**-connections plus serving **`epgm://`**-multicast services at once. Not speaking about MIL-STD-grade **`norm://`** Transport Class applications...

> **Q** : *" Differences between ZMTP and AMQP protocols ?"*

Quite many. The first one, the ZeroMQ being a universality & many-protocol & many-archetype equipped spin-off of AMQP ( refactored if not reinvented from the core-architecture all the way bottom-up ) having since v2.1+ endless list of language-bindings & wrappers, as evolution continues forwards.

AMQP being a lingua franca for Financial behemots' systems, that are not so keen on re-architecting the massively deployed status-quo in their systems.

AMQP is an agreed, evolving standard, not a Product per-se.

RabbitMQ is a Product, conform with some parts of the AMQP standard, while RabbitMQ may use wire-level protocol and other AMQP-standard parts for declared compatibility reasons, it is not an AMQP per-se.

Did I mention that ZeroMQ is a Broker-Less almost Zero-Latency framework?